# How to calculate the sum of values in jQuery using $('.shipping').val() and $('#pay').text()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum

How to sum `$('.shipping').val(zona);` and `$('#pay').text(total.toFixed(3));`

and then put the result into a span element like `<span class='amount'></span>` from script below

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.area").change(function() {
    var zone = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    var area = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
    $('.shipping').val(zone);
    $('.address').val(area);
  });
});

function updateTotalPrice() {
  var qty = parseInt($('#qty').val(), 10);
  var price = parseFloat($('#price').attr('value'));
  var total = qty * price;
  $('#pay').text(total.toFixed(3));
  $('#qty').text(total);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // set up event listeners 
  $('#plus-btn').click(function(event) {
    increaseCount(event, this);
  });
  $('#minus-btn').click(function(event) {
    decreaseCount(event, this);
  });
  $('#qty').change(function(event) {
    updateTotalPrice();
  });

  // update total price on page load 
  updateTotalPrice();
});

</script>
```

Comment: FYI. `$(this).children("option:selected").val()` can be simplified to `$(this).val()`.

Comment: `$('#qty').text(total);` doesn't make sense. `#qty` is an input, it doesn't have any text.

Comment: #qty used for displaying the text result only

Comment: Your code contains `var qty = parseInt($('#qty').val(), 10);` That means it's an input.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over all the `select.area` elements, calculating the total of their values.

```js
function updateTotalPrice() {
  var qty = parseInt($('#qty').val(), 10);
  var price = parseFloat($('#price').attr('value'));
  let shipping = 0;
  $("select.area").each(function() {
    shipping += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  var total = qty * price + shippting;
  $('#pay').text(total.toFixed(3));
}
```